# Issue with localization in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I have been stuck in a mysterious problem related to localization in the last two days.
I am trying to add languages to my app, but it seems to me that something is going wrong.

To make things simple, I added the following lines to my current app, to see if the word test will translate or not :

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> { [super viewDidLoad];
> UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
> lbl1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
> [self.view addSubview:lbl1];
> lbl1.text= NSLocalizedString(@"test", nil);
> }
> ```

After adding the language in the section of localization in "Project info" section, and checking "Use based internationalization". In addition to creating "Localizable.strings" file and clicking on Localize to choose the language, the word test does not translate.

BTW, here is `Localizable.strings` file :

> ```
> "test" = "test translated";
> ```

I've done clean, and deleted the app form my phone and build it again, but nothing changed !

I took the same code, and done the same steps by creating a new project on xCode, surprisingly it translates !

Anyone knows why the translation does NOT happen in my original app ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *Base Internationalization* is for storyboards, it is not for `NSLocalizedString`.

Secondly, the file should be **Localizable.strings**, not **Localization.strings**.

Comment: It is my mistake, I meant Localizable.strings

Comment: Go to the built products directory (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<your project>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos), right-click on your app and press **Show Package Contents**. In there, check that you have the corresponding **.lproj** folders with their own version of **Localizable.strings** available.

Comment: Localizable.strings are already there ! It may be something from my code ?

Comment: If the file is there and it contains that key ("test"), then I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

It happpened to me recently. I did those things:

1) Deleted app from simulator/iPhone

2) Cleaned app (Product -> Clean)

3) Deleted derived data (Window -> Organizer -> Projects (tab) -> (Select own project from left) -> Click "Delete..." on right of Derived data)

It helped me